Tridiagonal matrix LU decomposition and Floating Point Arithmetic
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m*m}$ be tridiagonal, that is
\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots \\
   a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} &a_{2,3} \\
   \dots  & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots  \\
   \cdots& & a_{n,n-1} & a_{n,n} 
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
A tridiagonal matrix has nonzero elements only on the main diagonal, the diagonal upon the main diagonal, and the diagonal below the main diagonal is the definition.
a)Assume that A is a floating point matrix and that $\bar{L}$ and $\bar{U}$ are computed(in floating point arithmetic) $L$ and $U$ respectively Show that $\bar{L}\bar{U}=A+\delta A$ where $||\delta_{A}||_{\infty}<u||\bar L||_{\infty}||\bar U||_{\infty}$ and $u$ is unit roundoff.
Actually I do not have an idea in this case but I have an example that this can happen when the matrix is not tridiagonal, when it is $2*2$.\begin{pmatrix}
  10^{-20} & 1\\ 
  1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, when I compute the $LU$ factorization of this matrix I find that  $L$=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\ 
  10^{20} & 1
\end{pmatrix} and
$U$=\begin{pmatrix}
  10^{-20} & 1\\ 
  0 & 1-10^{20}
\end{pmatrix}
and $\bar{L}$=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\ 
  10^{20} &1
\end{pmatrix}
and $\bar{U}$=\begin{pmatrix}
  10^{-20} & 1\\ 
  0 & -10^{20}
\end{pmatrix}
and here $\delta{A}$=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
and in my example the unir roundoff is $10^{-16}$ so the norm condition holds.That is an example when the matrix is not tridiagonal but I do not know how to generalize things and make progress.
